# How to check if ResponseWriter has been written

Tags: http, go, httpresponse

Using Golang's [net/http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package, how can I check if the `ResponseWriter` has been written to? I am receiving the following error message:

> http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls

Of course I can return booleans and such from my functions indicating weather I wrote to the `ResponseWriter` with a redirect or something, which I tried, but surely I am able to check if the `ResponseWriter` has been written to before I write to it with an easy method.

I am looking for a function that would look something like the following which I can use before I write to the `ResponseWriter`:

```
if w.Header().Get("Status-Code") == "" {
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Response Writer has already been written to.")
}
```

The code above doesn't seem to work... anyone have any idea how to check if the `ResponseWriter` has been written to or not?

Comment: I found a possible solution. Every time I write to the ResponseWriter with a redirect or file server, I could also set a custom header `w.Header().Set("custom", "1")` indicating it's been set and I could check with `w.Header().Get("custom") == "1"`

Comment: You could make your own version of `http.ResponseWriter` that sets a bool to true when `WriteHeader` is called. See https://play.golang.org/p/o6Tp9urYZZ.

Comment: Have a look at the [Gin framework](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/4a6bc4aac4607e253bcda67c8c5bcda693d2388e/response_writer.go). It implements a `Written()` method on the ResponseWriter

Comment: See example implementation of [storing and accessing written status code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34018537/1705598).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell if net/http's ResponseWriter.Write() has been called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897411/how-can-i-tell-if-net-https-responsewriter-write-has-been-called)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to do this is with a custom implementation of `http.ResponseWriter`:

```
type doneWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    done bool
}

func (w *doneWriter) WriteHeader(status int) {
    w.done = true
    w.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(status)
}

func (w *doneWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    w.done = true
    return w.ResponseWriter.Write(b)
}

func myMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        dw := &doneWriter{ResponseWriter: w}
        next.ServeHTTP(dw, r)
        if dw.done {
            // Something already wrote a response
            return
        }
        // Nothing else wrote a response
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        // Whatever you want here
    }
}
```

I also threw together [a simple package](https://godoc.org/github.com/flimzy/donewriter) to handle this for me. Feel free to use it as well if you like.